# Extracting Etymological Information from Wiktionary

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to extract the information in the Wiktionary's Etymology section of words. For example, give the word `telescope` in https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/telescope, I would like to scrape the section shown in the picture below:

[image: sample]

I tried scraping it but it is not always consistent in tag or class name. Instead, I used the official API, but I also could get to extract what I need. This is as best as I can get. https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext&titles=telescope

Can anyone recommend a way in which I can extract these info?

Comment: I tried to scrape the URL [https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext&titles=telescope](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext&titles=telescope) (note format parameter), and the output is exactly as the original topic, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKiCf.png). So what is the issue?

Comment: it gives you everything. I want to get the information in the etymology section only. I meant I cannot get any more specific in the API call. Does that make sense?

Comment: Why not just parse the etymology section from the entire response, using regex or split?

Comment: I will eventually go with that if there is no other neat way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of the MediaWiki API that I only found a few days ago. The old API is the "[Action API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page)" and the new one is the ["REST API"](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:REST_API).

The good news is that this REST API now includes [support for Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/api/rest_v1/#/Page%20content/get_page_definition__term_) (English only so far).

The bad news is that it does not return any information from the Etymology sections. Not yet anyway. You can probably join [the mailing list](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/wikitech-l) or file a feature request.